# Is it possible to put more than two prepositions before a relative pronoun?

Tags: prepositions, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

I think the following is OK:

> I was talking to whom he was looking at.

#### Question:

Can I move the 'at' in front of the 'whom'?
So the sentence will be:

> I was talking to at whom he was looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Can I move the 'at' in front of the 'whom'?"

No.

- Generally speaking (there are probably exceptions), you don't put two prepositions in a row. You don't aggregate prepositions by appending them to each other, such as "through in", "into on", "at by", "to at".
- English follows strict ordering rules.  The majority of the time you must keep a specific order. There isn't a huge amount of flexibility such as you are proposing.
- "Looking at" is a [phrasal verb](https://www.skypeenglishclasses.com/english-phrasal-verbs/). "At" is a particle associated with "looking". A particle comes after a verb, either immediately, or after some interceding words.  It does not precede the verb.

Comment: Compare the common expression _put up with (something)._ _With_ is a preposition; _up_ isn't.

Answer (score 1):

I was talking to whom he was looking at. ***incorrect***

I was talking to at whom he was looking. ***even more incorrect***

**Correct examples**

I was talking to the person he was looking at.

or

I was talking to the one he was looking at.